# Upgrade from Magento 1.8, 1.9 -> 2.0

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8, upgrade

I'm currently on Magento 1.8 and want to get to Magento 2.0

Would it be recommended I first upgrade 1.8 -> 1.9.? before attempting the 2.0 upgrade?

Comment: You can directly upgrade your site from Magento 1.8 to Magento 2.

Comment: Is the re-implementing of my theme significant on 2.0?  Or, should it just work.   If it is significant work, I may consider moving to 1.9 as a step to cleanup my theming, modified core files, etc. since the developer created somewhat of a mess.

Comment: Migration take only data from Magento 1 to Magneto 2.

Comment: I see, I think that I understand that to mean if I migrate from Magento 1 to Magento 2 it is a data-only migration, I would be starting from scratch with extensions, themes, etc. so it is a safe/easy upgrade.  Correct?

Comment: you should change the theme and extensions. all the file structures is change

Comment: yes, you need to change all the things like extension and theme from starting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the various comments on my original question, and looking at the Magento documentation, it sounds like the best practice is to essentially build the new site from scratch on 2.0.   Well, not exactly from scratch, Magento has tools to 'migrate' the data from older versions to 2.0.  So effectively, you install Magento 2.0, migrate your data, and create new templates.    From the docs it looks like it also supports incremental migration after you do your initial migration in case more transactions (new customers, orders, invoices, etc.) occur on your older site.  This make sense since the initial migration can be very slow, but then updating just the new data can allow for a quick cut-over to the new version.

Much more information in the Magento 2.0 migration guide, found [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/migration/bk-migration-guide.html).